# Facebook - syncing comments social plugin with comments on object's?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Currently i am adding the social plugins to my site. Specifically to my photo albums. To generate the albums i am using fql to grab all the albums from a certain page. So it then occurred to me that people will be commenting inside of facebook but the social plugin will only show comments for the url not for the photo's object inside facebook. I know i can get the object_id from the fql. Is there a way to link the two together so if a user comments on either my site or facebook it will be all included.

So i am a little stumped i looked around the graph api for quite some time with no luck so anybody have any ideas? :\

cheers guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there isn't currently a plugin  that lets you put an Object_id into and it will grab all of the comments out for that object.

You will need to use the graph api and if the album is public then you will not need a oauth code to access the comments. Once you have this object just convert it to a a stand-object array and do what you will with it ;)